# Convert base64 to image and save it in temp folder flutter

Tags: flutter, caching, dart, base64

I have base64 string of image like */9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA0JCgsKCA0LCgsODg0PEyAVExISEyccHhcgLikxMC4pLSwzOko+MzZGNywtQFdBRkxOUlNSMj5aYVpQYEpRUk//....*

What I want to do is to save this image in temp folder and use that file address for showing image in my app.

How can I do that?

Comment: This post might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669785/how-to-save-image-from-base64-string-to-file-in-flutter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as syspaths;
```

**Decode your base64 string to bytes in memory.**

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(base64String);
```

**Make a temporary directory and file on that directory**

```
final appDir = await syspaths.getTemporaryDirectory();
File file = File('${appDir.path}/sth.jpg');
```

**Write converted bytes on a file**

```
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes)
```

**then we can**

```
Image.file(file);
```

> OR ALTERNATIVELY

**Decode your base64 string to bytes in memory.**

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(base64String);
```

**then we can**

```
Image.memory(bytes)
```